# Running certain steps once before a scenario outline - Python Behave

Tags: python, bdd, scenarios, python-behave

As the title suggests, I wish to run some certain configuration / environment setup steps before a scenario outline. I know there is `Background` to do this for scenarios, but Behave splits a scenario outline into multiple scenarios and thus runs the background for every input in the scenario outline.

This is not what I want. For certain reasons I cannot provide the code I am working with however I will write up an example feature file.

```
Background: Power up module and connect
Given the module is powered up
And I have a valid USB connection

Scenario Outline: Example
    When I read the arduino
    Then I get some <'output'>

Example: Outputs
| 'output' |
| Hi       |
| No       |
| Yes      |
```

What would happen in this case is Behave would power cycle and check USB connection for each output `Hi`, `No`, `Yes` resulting in three power cycles and three connection checks

What I want is for Behave to power cycle once and check the connection once and then run all three tests.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet is probably to use the `before_feature` environment hook and either a)
tags on the feature and/or b) the feature name directly.

For example:

**some.feature**

```
@expensive_setup
Feature: some name
  description
  further description

  Background: some requirement of this test
    Given some setup condition that runs before each scenario
      And some other setup action

  Scenario: some scenario
      Given some condition
       When some action is taken
       Then some result is expected.

  Scenario: some other scenario
      Given some other condition
       When some action is taken
       Then some other result is expected.
```

**steps/environment.py**

```
def before_feature(context, feature):
    if 'expensive_setup' in feature.tags:
        context.execute_steps('''
            Given some setup condition that only runs once per feature
              And some other run once setup action
        ''')
```

**alternate steps/environment.py**

```
def before_feature(context, feature):
    if feature.name == 'some name':
        context.execute_steps('''
            Given some setup condition that only runs once per feature
              And some other run once setup action
        ''')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing exactly the same problem.
There is an **expensive** `Background`, which should be performed only once per `Feature`. 
What is actually needed to solve that problem, is the ability to store state between `Scenario`s.

My solution for this problem was to use `behave.runner.Context#_root` which is kept throughout the whole run. I know what accessing private members is not a good practice - I will be very happy to learn cleaner way.

```
# XXX.feature file
Background: Expensive setup
  Given we have performed our expensive setup

# steps/XXX.py file
@given("we have performed our expensive setup")
def step_impl(context: Context):    
    if not context._root.get('initialized', False):
        # expensive_operaion.do()
        context._root['initialized'] = True
```

Comment: I believe [TomDotDom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40923708/6252525) is the correct approach.  You _can_ do it this way, but this is what the `steps/enviroment.py` is intended for, and in comparison, this way feels a little "hacky".

Answer (score 0):

You Can do this :

1. Create environment.py in Features folder
2. Inside environment.py : from behave import fixture
3. Write Code :

from behave import fixture

def before_feature(context, feature):
print("Runs Before Each Feature")

def after_feature(context, feature):
print("Run After Each Feature")

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
print("Run Before Each Scenario")

def after_scenario(context, scenario):
print("Run After Each Scenario")

#Now run your Tc : Your O/P will be
Runs Before Each Feature
Run Before Each Scenario
Run After Each Scenario
Run After Each Feature

Comment: Why would you mention `import fixture` in this example? And no, neither `before_feature` nor `before_scenario` give you control over *scenario outlines*, which the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Background. You should use Scenario. If you use Background, Background steps repeat. But use Scenario keywords, steps can not repeat.

```
Feature: Example
Scenario: Scenario for Background
  When Login Step
  Then Verify Login Successfully
 Scenario Outline: Example
   When I read the arduino
    Then I get some <'output'>

Example: Outputs
| 'output' |
| Hi       |
| No       |
| Yes      |
```